# Increase the height of the tag "p" and align the center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am creating a menu to my site in `ul.buttons`.
In it I have a title, `span.button-title`, a sub-title `span` and a code `p`.
This code must be aligned vertically to the center, half of the title and subtitle.

How to make the autura the tag `p` (in red) will have the same autura of `div.button`. I tried `height: 100%;` but failed.

After her stay with the same height, I would align the tag `p` in the center, vertical.

[See](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/11/) the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/5jJg3/12/) with some changes.

First, `inline-block` elements don't consider the vertical size. So it's necessary changing to `block` and do the horizontal align with `float`.

Then, elements cannot use `height: 100%` if their parent has no fixed height. Then a height was set to the `button` class.